# UITableView setContentOffset not working in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm loading my table from nib file, and in `viewDidLoad` I can't do anything with the table. I can use table's delegate methods to set the contentOffset, and they work, but it doesn't work in `viewDidLoad`.

So is the table even loaded in `viewDidLoad`? Probably not. Any idea how to fix it, or check if the table has loaded? (without subclassing)

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to move your call to `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: This would be stupid. But yeah I did.

Comment: OK, maybe this method can be useful to you `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table view is loaded in viewDidLoad, but normally there is no data in it yet. Calling reloadData in viewDidLoad will cause the data to be loaded and the rows to be populated.

Once there is data in the table, and the contentSize of the table is larger than the bounds.size, the tableview will respond appropriately to setContentOffset.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue but the solution above didn't work for me. It's possible because I am using auto layout or because it's been years since this question was answered.

What worked for me was using viewDidLayoutSubviews. Only then the setOffset worked.

Comment: Wow really strange why it dod not work from `viewDidload`, only from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.